# What is rav endpoint protection in an old legacy set of bios,mine just says ravs

Tags: bios, uefi, firmware, legacy

From what I understand is uefi is the new version of bios @nd legacy is the old blue screen just like legacy usb is the old 2.0 sub,and yes if your firmware supports uefi you can boot versions of Windows into the newer version of uefi and vice versa...I was looking into it ,but I haven't  double checked my firmware yet,this system is 12 years old or more if you can imagine that....anyway tab end point anyone?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your question is most unclear (to me).  I have a ten year old ThinkPad that upgraded to UEFI when it was Windows 8 and is now running an advanced version of Windows 11. What is your question?  Plain language please.